# Array of Dictionaries

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have an `NSMutableArray`, `purDesc`, that holds an `NSMutableDictionary`, `purDetails`. When I use `NSLog(@"%@", purDesc);` it returns empty spaces where there should be dictionarys as follows:

```
singleton purDesc Dump:(
        {
    },
        {
    },
        {
    },
        {
    },
        {
    }
)
```

Now the size/look/dump changes every time I add a dictionary to reflect the number of times a dictionary gets added/removed. Here are the code snippets taken from my XML parser:

...

```
else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"purDesc"])
{
    //close purDisc
    // dumps dictionary into log
    NSLog(@"End of purDesc");
    NSLog(@"Dump:%@", [purDesc description]);

    [singleton setPurDesc:purDesc];//sets this response to the response in the singleton

    NSLog(@"singleton purDesc Dump:%@", [[singleton purDesc] description]);
    return;//we're done here
}
else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"PurDetails"])
{
    //close purDetails
    // dumps dictionary into log
    NSLog(@"End of PurDetails");
    [purDetails addEntriesFromDictionary:description];//sets current purDetails to current description
    NSLog(@"Dump:%@", [purDetails description]);

    [purDesc addObject:purDetails];//adds purDetails dictionary to purDesc
    [purDetails removeAllObjects];
    NSLog(@"Current purDesc:%@", [purDesc description]); 
}
```

What am I doing wrong and why is the log coming up semi-empty?

Comment: How are you actually filling the array and the dictionaries? I guess the dictionaries *are* empty. what is singleton, and what is [singleton purDesc]? How does it relate to purDesc? It is hard to actually see what is going on, let alone what is wrong.

Comment: If I log them it shows the values. For example, NSLog(@"Dump:%@", [purDetails description]); returns Dump:{
    amt = "1.29";
    desc = test;
}

Comment: Yes, but that is purDetails. I'd need to see more code to see what is what and what is wrong.

Comment: purDetails is placed into purDesc via [purDesc addObject:purDetails]; but when logged on the line two lines down, it shows the { }. If I add another purDetails to purDesc, purDesc shows { } { }. If I add another it becomes { } { } { }, etc etc.

Comment: By the way, you don't need to `NSLog` `[... description]`. It suffices to just do `NSLog(@"%@",purDesc)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see that you do:

```
[purDesc addObject:purDetails];//adds purDetails dictionary to purDesc
[purDetails removeAllObjects];
```

That stores a ***reference*** to *purDetails* in *purDesc*, and increments its retain count, but it ***does not make a copy***. So if you *removeAllObjects*, the contents of the dictionary are lost. The fact you "stored" a reference to it in *purDesc* doesn't change that. I guess what you see is the result of this or a similar action.

You can't re-use the dictionary. You'll have to alloc and init a new one each time. You should *release* the local one you have, but not clear it.

I'd need to see more code to see how you can improve your design thus that this is not a problem and memory management is taken care of properly.

Comment: For anyone else who finds it, I just removed the line [purDetails removeAllObjects]; and now I alloc and init every time I need a new one.

Comment: Be sure to be aware of the memory management (and especially the reference counting) issues involving this, though. You should release what you allocate. It just takes some experience to know when to release. It took me a few weeks to get it right, and I still have to think hard about such things, sometimes. I assume that ARC will make this a little easier.

Comment: Already using ARC. ;) I did check for leaks about ten minutes ago (before seeing your reply) and I'm good to go. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Yes, ARC makes most of the worries about retain/release go away. Delphi has had this for many many years already, for interfaces, and it makes things a lot easier.